# How to find Pdf file in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

hello i am beginner in iOS In one of my activity i want to ask .....I displayed pdf using WebView ......on screen and save this Pdf then write this type of code ........

```
 NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *pdfFilePath =[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];// your yourPdfFile file here
 NSLog(@"pdf file %@",pdfFilePath);
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfFilePath];
 UIDocumentInteractionController *docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];

 docController.delegate = self;
 [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRextZero inView:self.view  animated:YES];
```

When we run this code on simulator (using Xcode) then show path and I got this Pdf file successfully in documents folder .......
but when we run this code in iPhone device then I got this type of path......

```
/var/mobile/Applications/D33A80AA-C0AD-4211-ADE3-4906372CDA40/Documents/myPDF.pdf
```

So I don't know where is my Pdf in iPhone device and how to got this Pdf and open .....when i want ......

Comment: we can not determine document folder in Device like Simulator. we get path as you post only

Answer (score 0):

If your PDF is in the documents folder, you should retrieve the path like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
```

Don't try to use anything related to the absolute path as you see it in the simulator.

One reason you might not find a file on the device where you do find it on the simulator is that the simulator is case-insensitive but the device is case-sensitive, so be sure your names match exactly.

But! Be aware that the Documents folder is now perhaps not where you want to be storing things - unless you are sure you want them backed up with iCloud. The [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) says to use Documents ONLY for documents that cannot be recreated by the app, "critical" documents. A lot of the time it makes sense to store them in the user Library folder instead. In that case the arguments to NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains would be:

```
(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)
```